# Clean the reply from Redis

Tags: c, database, nosql, redis, hiredis

I'm currently building an high speed application which needs to update values on the a redis database using hiredis c library. Currently using pipelined mode for a faster write, to speed up further I don't actually read the reply and free them at all.

1. Will not reading the reply a bad design?
2. Is there a way to setup redis to not reply at all? To cut the Round Trip Time.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: 1 -> Yes, bad design; 2 -> No; but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13025165/can-redis-disable-the-replies-for-pipelined-commands/13025646#13025646 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270126/how-can-i-execute-commands-in-redis-without-getting-any-response-at-all/14281848#14281848

Comment: Thanks Didier Spezia, I will try the Asynchronous method.